# mongoose - Find by created time irrelevant of date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following mongoose model

```
const Post = new Schema({
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
  updated_at: { type: Date },
  postName: String,
  postContent:String,
  promoted: {
    isPromoted: { type: Boolean, default: false, required: true },
    promotedFrom: { type: Date },
    promotedTill: { type: Date },
  },
});
```

**Example Document**

```
const Post = new Schema({
  created_at: 2020-07-05T16:16:38.139+00:00,
  postName: My first Post,
  postContent:This is my furst post,
  promoted: {
    isPromoted: true,
    promotedFrom: 2020-11-13T16:14:38.139+00:00,
    promotedTill: 2020-11-20T16:14:38.139+00:00,
  },
});
```

With mongose I want to query the documents with the promotedTill time to be between 12.00 hrs to 16.30 hrs irrespective of any date.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the `gt` and `lt` to include/exclude boundaries:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$match: {$expr: {
            $and: [
{$gt: [ {$hour: "$promoted.promotedTill"}, 12 ]},
{$lte: [{$hour: "$promoted.promotedTill"},16]},
{$lt: [{$minute: "$promoted.promotedTill"},30]}
                    ]}
    }}

  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

check this [example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/p1UFqv2XyVG)

I've done the query quite simple, without other fields.

The query is this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$and": [
    {
      "promoted.promotedFrom": {
        "$gte": ISODate("yourdate")
      }
    },
    {
      "promoted.promotedTill": {
        "$lte": ISODate("yordate")
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Basically is search a value within a range using `$gte` (greater than or equal) and `$lte` (lower than or equal).

Using the `$and` operator both conditions should be true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to filter the document by hour in a date. not by a number

Comment: I've added an example with dates. But, as I've said, is exactly the same. Mongo treats dates and numbers comparsion in the same way. So, if a query works comparing numbers, it will work with dates. Check the second example.

Comment: From your second example, you have filtered by date,which will give me all the document between the start date and end date. but my requirement is to filter by start time and endtime.

Comment: You can place the date you want into the query. You can create a date into js or whatever you want and pass it to mongo query. That's your question or have I missunderstood something?

Comment: The question is misunderstood. If my from time is 12.00 and to time is 16.30, document with time 11.59 should not be retrieved

Comment: Then, you want `promotedFrom >= date <= promotedTill` ? You only have to change the object key you want to read. The query is the same.